# Android MediaPlayer dispose of video correctly

Tags: android, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to create a Xamarin Forms application that displays a full screen video for the launch page. Once loading is complete the launch page takes you to the home screen. The home screen displays a series of videos in a carousel.

On Android the carousel videos work fine by themselves but when I add in the launch screen video it displays over the carousel ones. Currently I have a View called VideoView in my App that has a BindableProperty for the video source.

The rendering is done platform specifically in a custom renderer that is below. It uses a native VideoView and MediaPlayer control for Android. I have tried the various dispose and and release functions in the OnDisappearing function in the launch screen, but none of them seem to release the video.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(App.Renderers.VideoView), 
typeof(VideoViewRenderer))]
namespace App.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class VideoViewRenderer : 
    ViewRenderer<App.Renderers.VideoView, VideoView>, ISurfaceHolderCallback
    {
        private VideoView videoview;
        private MediaPlayer player;

        public void SurfaceChanged(ISurfaceHolder holder, global::Android.Graphics.Format format, int width, int height)
        {
        }

        public void SurfaceDestroyed(ISurfaceHolder holder)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<App.Renderers.VideoView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            e.NewElement.StopAction = () =>
            {
                player.Pause();
            };

            e.NewElement.StartAction = () =>
            {
                player.Start();
            };

            e.NewElement.DisposeAction = () => 
            {
                Control.StopPlayback();
                Control.Dispose();
                player.Stop();
                player.Reset();
                player.Release();
            };

            if (Control == null)
            {
                videoview = new VideoView(Context);
                base.SetNativeControl(videoview);
                Control.Holder.AddCallback(this);
                player = new MediaPlayer();
                play(e.NewElement.FileSource);
            }
        }

        void play(string fullPath)
        {
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = Forms.Context.Assets.OpenFd(fullPath);
            if (afd != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    player.SetDataSource(afd.FileDescriptor, afd.StartOffset, afd.Length);
                    player.Prepare();
                    player.Looping = true;
                    Control.Layout(0, 200, player.VideoHeight, player.VideoWidth);
                    player.SetVideoScalingMode(VideoScalingMode.ScaleToFit);
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
        }

        public void SurfaceCreated(ISurfaceHolder holder)
        {
            player.SetDisplay(holder);
        }
    }
}
```

The VideoView class extends View and is as follows:

```
public class VideoView : View
{
    public Action StopAction;
    public Action StartAction;
    public Action DisposeAction;

    public VideoView()
    {
        FileSource = string.Empty;
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty FileSourceProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create<VideoView, string>(
            p => p.FileSource, string.Empty);

    public string FileSource
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(FileSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FileSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (StopAction != null)
            StopAction();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (DisposeAction != null)
            DisposeAction();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (StartAction != null)
            StartAction();
    }
}
```

And finally usage of the view is as follows:

```
<controls:VideoView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="Video1" FileSource="big_buck_bunny.mp4" Margin="0,10,0,40" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by not disposing it? Are you sure the method is being called in the renderer? I'm almost certain your e.NewElement.DisposeAction is doing everything correctly. Btw, you should also deattach the actions in `OnElementChanged - if(e.OldElement != null) e.OldElement -= deattach`

Comment: You should do 3 checks in your `OnElementChanged`: `if(Control != null) ... SetNativeControl(ctrl);` // `if(e.OldElement != null) e.OldElement -= events` // `if(e.NewElement != null) e.NewElement += events`

Comment: I put in a breakpoint and it does reach the dispose function and calls everything inside it. The old video just continues to display (in the same aspect ratio as on the launch screen).

Comment: Can you elaborate once more? So you have a launchpage showing a fullscreen video and a homepage with a carousel view that holds multiple videos, am i right? If so, what do you mean by "Once loading is complete the launch page takes you to the home screen."

Comment: When the loading screen is done it shows the homescreen (the one with the carousel of videos). But the loading screen video is still displayed in place of the carousel videos.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: It turns out by using navigationpage it was keeping a reference to the loading screen. The children of the AbsoluteLayout that contained the video had to be removed in the OnDisappearing function and the video set to null.

Comment: @Zoosmell, I am facing the same issue. Can you post the answer that resolved your issue?